# how to reverse queryset without getting error: AttributeError: 'reversed' object has no attribute 'values'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

I want to reverse the order of the following queryset, but I get the error `AttributeError: 'reversed' object has no attribute 'values'`. I believe this is because of the `reversed_instances.values()`. Without changing `reversed_instances.values()`, how can I reverse the order of instances? Thank you, and please leave a comment at the bottom.

```
def view(request, pk):

    instances = Calls.objects.filter(var=var).order_by('-date')[:3]
    reversed_instances = reversed(instances )

    return JsonResponse({"calls":list(reversed_instances.values())})
```

Comment: How can it work ? When you do `reversed` on a queryset it returns a list and list doesn't have `values`

Answer (score 0):

You are calling [values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#values) on [reversed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) object which doesn't have this attribute you need to do it on a queryset like this:

```
def view(request, pk):

    instances = Calls.objects.filter(var=var).order_by('-date')[:3].values()
    reversed_instances = reversed(instances)

    return JsonResponse({"calls":list(reversed_instances)})
```